# Overloaded method value apply with alternatives with optional type class

Tags: scala, play-json

I'm trying to parse my case classes to and from JsObject but get hit with an overloaded method error that isn't clear to me.

The error message says "overloaded method value apply with alternatives".

Here is the reads code:

```scala
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._


implicit val accountCreatedReads: Reads[AccountCreated] = (
      (JsPath \ "eventId").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "timestamp").read[OffsetDateTime] and
      (JsPath \ "accountId").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "accountAttributes").readNullable[Attributes] and
      (JsPath \ "expirationTime").readNullable[Long]
  )(AccountCreated.apply _)
```

And here is the case class:

```scala
case class AccountCreated(
  eventId: String,
  timestamp: OffsetDateTime,
  accountId: String,
  accountAttributes: Option[Attributes] = None,  // This is the line the error refers to
  expirationTime: Option[Long] = None
)
```

Here is the class that represents the attributes:

```scala
type Attributes = JsValue
```

Can someone help me out here? This is the first time I've used this part of play-json, so I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Please provide the input json that you are trying to de-serialize

Answer (score 1):

So you want to read Attributes as Json.

```
 implicit val accountCreatedReads: Reads[AccountCreated] = (
      (JsPath \ "eventId").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "timestamp").read[OffsetDateTime] and
      (JsPath \ "accountId").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "accountAttributes").readNullable[String].map(Json.parse(_)) and //returns JsValue
      (JsPath \ "expirationTime").readNullable[Long]
  )(AccountCreated.apply _)
```

If it is really a JSON then

```
(JsPath \ "accountAttributes").readNullable[String].map(Json.parse(_))
```

should be able to parse it without a problem.